# Ansible: setting a variable to a string

Tags: ansible

I have the followinf Ansible code:

```
- name: "Set variable"
  set_fact:
    my_var: "{{ ((all_vars | from_yaml).metadata.annotations['var'] | default(undefined)) | from_json }}"
```

If 'var' is not present/declared I would like to set it to string "undefined".

I've tried using single and double quotes like this `default("undefined")` and it didn't help.

It fails with:

> The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({{ ((all_vars | from_yaml).metadata.annotations['var'] | default(undefined)) | from_json }}).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `undefined` is being interpreted as a variable, since it is not quoted. To set it to the string "undefined", you need to quote it:

```yaml
- name: "Set variable"
  set_fact:
    my_var: "{{ ((all_vars | from_yaml).metadata.annotations['var'] | default('undefined')) }}"
```

The `default()` filter requires the value to be a quoted string, number, boolean, etc. By passing `undefined` without quotes, Ansible thinks it is a variable name rather than a literal string.

Quoting it as `'undefined'` makes it a string literal, which will then be used as the default value if 'var' is not present.

With all of that being said:

- `default(undefined)` - tries to use a variable called undefined
- `default("undefined")` - sets the default to the string "undefined"

Comment: Hi @itsmedannyc, I still get the error even when I use quotes around the string:
Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key.   
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value

Comment: if I remove "| from_json" then it works

Comment: @anechkayf I've updated my answer. Please mark as complete if it helped you :)

Comment: could you please explain why it didn't work with from_json filter?